# How to convert TypeScript interface to Go struct?

Tags: typescript, go, struct, types, interface

I'm trying to convert my object modeling tool, built with TypeScript, to Go.

What I have in TypeScript is:

```
interface SchemaType {
  [key: string]: {
    type: string;
    required?: boolean;
    default?: any;
    validate?: any[];
    maxlength?: any[];
    minlength?: any[],
    transform?: Function;
  };
};

class Schema {
  private readonly schema;

  constructor(schema: SchemaType) {
    this.schema = schema;
  };

  public validate(data: object): Promise<object> {
    // Do something with data
    return data;
  };
};
```

So that I can then do:

```
const itemSchema = new Schema({
  id: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  createdBy: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});
```

I've only gotten this far with Go:

```
type SchemaType struct {
  Key       string // I'm not sure about this bit
  Type      string
  Required  bool
  Default   func()
  Validate  [2]interface{}
  Maxlength [2]interface{}
  Minlength [2]interface{}
  Transform func()
}

type Schema struct {
    schema SchemaType
}

func (s *Schema) NewSchema(schema SchemaType) {
    s.schema = schema
}

func (s *Schema) Validate(collection string, data map[string]interface{}) map[string]interface{} {
    // do something with data
    return data
}
```

I'm a little stuck mainly because of the dynamic "key" in the SchemaType interface and am not sure how to replicate this in Go...

Comment: Why would you do that? Typescript and go are entirely different languages. What do you want to achieve? (See: [what is the xy problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt - just added some more context as to what I'm trying to achieve...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[key string]:` part means that it's a dictionary with keys of type `string`. In Go that would be a `map[string]<some type>`.

```
type SchemaType map[string]SchemaTypeEntry

type SchemaTypeEntry struct {
  Type      string
  Required  bool
  // ...
}
```

or, drop the `SchemaType` type and change `Schema`:

```
type Schema struct {
    schema map[string]SchemaTypeEntry
}
```

Now, about the other fields, the look odd as you have defined them, and it's likely that it will not work the way you are showing here.

`Default` would be a value, not a `func()` (a function that doesn't return anything). You don't know what type the value is, so the type should be `interface {}` or `any` (since Go 1.18 - an alias for `interface {}`).

`Transform` - that would likely be a function that takes a value, transforms it, and returns a value - `func(interface{}) interface{}`

No idea what `MinLength`, `MaxLength` and `Validate` stand for in this context - it is unclear why they are arrays in Javascript, and how you can be sure that they are of exactly length 2 in Go.